# How to check if a browser supports shadow DOM

Tags: css, dom, polymer, shadow

One way would be to check if there is a .shadowRoot property on an element, however I need to return a boolean before the page is rendered.

Comment: Since you're going to run your code before the rest of the page loads anyway, blocking everything until your code is done, create an element, check, remove it, continue on.

Comment: A bit more specific but I wanted to see if shadow parts were supported - this worked 'part' in HTMLElement.prototype; // true if "part" is supported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730398/how-to-check-if-a-browser-supports-shadow-dom?lq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One simple feature test would be:

```
if (document.head.createShadowRoot || document.head.attachShadow) {
    // I can shadow DOM
} else {
    // I can't
}
```

This will work even if you include the script in the head section and assumes no malicious scripts were added prior to yours (a safe assumption).

Currently, Chrome, Opera, and derived browsers (like Android browsers) support it.
For more information, visit: https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1 and http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom

Comment: Is there something I can check against in `window`?  I need to test before the page is loaded (selenium).

Comment: nm, this appears to work in wdio.io setup/before function.  Still interested in an answer, however.

Comment: this has a false negative in safari 10.1, as it is v0. V1 uses `attachShadow`

Comment: I added `<script> const CAN_SHADOW = !!(document.head.attachShadow || document.head.createShadowRoot);</script>` to the head of my Polymer app's test/index.html, BEFORE I load webcomponents-loader.js. Works fine