# Conditional comments not working in ie11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I'm trying to use conditional comments to load webcomponents polymer polyfill on ie11 and webcomponente-lite polyfill on ohter browser so I have:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/roboto-condensed/css/roboto-condensed.css">
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The issue is that webcomponents-lite.min.js is always loaded, event in IE11

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE 11 does not support conditional comments.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Conditional comments are no longer supported
>
> Impact Applies to Internet Explorer 10 and later. Affects IE10
>   Standards mode and later, including interoperable quirks mode. Support
>   for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10
>   standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change
>   can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or
>   pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet
>   Explorer.

You'll need to try another way to target IE11 specifically.

[Searching around SO brought me to this answer, which uses feature detection to determine whether or not to load Polymer's polyfills.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33415889/78738)