# How to check if a browser supports Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, polymer

How am I able to check (JS or HTML code) whether Polymer is supported by the current browser or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Short answer:

*Quick test: Firefox 38.0.5 alerts "No", while Chrome 44.0.2403.130 m alerts "Yes"*

```js
function supportsPolymer() {
  return 'content' in document.createElement('template') && 'import' in document.createElement('link') && 'registerElement' in document && document.head.createShadowRoot;
}

if(supportsPolymer()) {
  
  //Good to go
  alert("Yes");
  
} else {
  
  //Is not supported
  alert("No");
  
}
```

### Detailed answer:

You've to check [this list](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html) on Polymer's website.

> - Template
> - HTML Imports
> - Custom Elements
> - Shadow DOM

These features have to be supported:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

> ```
> function supportsTemplate() {
>   return 'content' in document.createElement('template');
> }
>
> if (supportsTemplate()) {
>   // Good to go!
> } else {
>   // Use old templating techniques or libraries.
> }
> ```

---

- https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/platform/html-imports.html

> ```
> function supportsImports() {
>   return 'import' in document.createElement('link');
> }
>
> if (supportsImports()) {
>   // Good to go!
> } else {
>   // Use other libraries/require systems to load files.
> }
> ```

---

- https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/platform/custom-elements.html

> ```
> function supportsCustomElements() {
>   return 'registerElement' in document;
> }
>
> if (supportsCustomElements()) {
>   // Good to go!
> } else {
>   // Use other libraries to create components.
> }
> ```

---

- https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/platform/shadow-dom.html

[How to check if a browser supports shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730398/how-to-check-if-a-browser-supports-shadow-dom)

> ```
> if(document.head.createShadowRoot) {
>     // I can shadow DOM
> } else {
>     // I can't
> }
> ```

In a function:

```
 function supportsShadowDom() {
   return document.head.createShadowRoot;
 }
```

Untested version in the style of the previous snippets:

```
 function supportsShadowDom() {
   return 'createShadowRoot' in document;
 }
```

---

Okay, after you've implemented every function you can do something like this:

```
 if (supportsCustomElements() && supportsTemplate() && supportsImports() && supportsShadowDom()) {
   // Good to go!
 } else {
   // Use other libraries to create components.
 }
```

This is the current matrix from https://github.com/WebComponents/webcomponentsjs#browser-support:

```html
<table><thead>
<tr>
<th>Polyfill</th>
<th align="center">IE10</th>
<th align="center">IE11+</th>
<th align="center">Chrome*</th>
<th align="center">Firefox*</th>
<th align="center">Safari 7+*</th>
<th align="center">Chrome Android*</th>
<th align="center">Mobile Safari*</th>
</tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>Custom Elements</td>
<td align="center">~</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HTML Imports</td>
<td align="center">~</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shadow DOM</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Templates</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
<td align="center">✓</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

This may be interesting, too: 
https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/26