# Detect Google Polymer browser compatibility

Tags: browser, polymer, compatibility, detection

I am writing a project using polymer.  Right now, if a browser doesn't support it most of the page is just blank.  Is there a way to quickly if the users browser supports polymer and if not, prompt them to use a modern browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a browser supports Polymer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965266/how-to-check-if-a-browser-supports-polymer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the page http://caniuse.com/ and ask for the technology that is being used in the framework you want to implement,  **Shadow dom** and **Custom elements** in this case I think that are the main things that polymer uses and that don't allow this framework to be used all over the place in any browser